# Git setting to allow force update of certain branches

Tags: git, githooks

On our git server we have a git config of

```
[receive]
    denyDeletes = true
    denynonfastforwards = true
```

This is a very sensible setting as it stops mistaken force updates on the *important* branches. However there are many branches that it would be useful to force update.

Rather than having this global setting is there an easy way to achieve this functionality.

I assume it possible through a git pre-recieve hook, however I am not sure how I would check whether the push is a forced non fast forward.

I'm aware there are complete solutions through Git hosting software such as gitolite, but I'm looking to achieve this on a simple ssh based server.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an update hook.  It is called once for each reference being updated with three parameters: (1) the ref name, (2) the pre-update commit-id of that branch (or '0'*40 if you're creating the branch), and (3) the post-update commit-id of that branch (or '0'*40 if you're deleting that branch).  If it's not a create or destroy, then you can run `git merge-base old-rev new-rev`.  If the result is the same as the old-rev, the update is a fast-forward.  Otherwise, the update is a force push of something not descended from the previous head.

In my update hook, I allow force updates for branches that start with the user's name, e.g., wolf can force push any branch in `wolf/*`, but only a whitelist of users can update those branches without a prefix, e.g., `master`.

Here's a link to an example update hook that does exactly that, as used in the Allura project at SourceForge: https://forge-allura.apache.org/p/allura/git/ci/master/tree/scripts/git-hooks/for-the-remote-repo/update[update](https://forge-allura.apache.org/p/allura/git/ci/master/tree/scripts/git-hooks/for-the-remote-repo/update)